Selecting Python Interpreter inside Docker in Codespaces
I have a mono repo that uses Codespaces. The codespace uses Docker to run services and I would want to use the Python interpreter inside one container when Selecting the Python Interpreter in VS Code.
How can I achieve this? When trying to select the interpreter I just have the interpreters inside the Codespace, and nothing related to docker containers.


Please use remote-SSH extension. This way is the same to the solution of this issue.  https://www.docker.com/blog/
